# What does $ \lvert z-a \rvert = \mathit Re(z)+a $ look like?

Tags: complex-numbers, locus

What does a loci with the equation look like?

$ \lvert z-a \rvert = \mathit Re(z)+a $

This is for the applying complex numbers topic of an advanced HSC maths course. I was asked to describe the loci.

I know that $ \lvert z-a \rvert $ would get me either a perpendicular bisector or a circle. I also know that $ \mathit Re(z) $ refers to the horizontal values on the complex plane. But I just can't imagine what it looks like.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be put on hold. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: take $z=x+iy$ and $Re(z)=x$ and solve

Answer (score -1, accepted):

We can treat complex numbers $z = x + iy$ as equations over $(x, y) \in \mathbb R^2$, and use a geometry plotter to plot them. In this case, the equation system is:

$$
\begin{align*}
|x + iy - a| &= Re(x+iy) + a \\
|(x - a) + iy| &= x + a\\
\sqrt{(x-a)^2 + y^2} &= x + a \\
(x-a)^2 + y^2 &= (x + a)^2
\end{align*}
$$

One can use a tool like [Desmos](https://www.desmos.com/calculator) for plotting curves like these. In this case, [here is a playable version of the graph with $a$ as a parameter](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/ogkzaj6lnu).

The image for one choice of $a$ is:
[image: tical]

Comment: @Deepak you are right

Comment: @Deepak  i think in answer it should be $(x+a)^2$

Comment: Using this method, shouldn't the final equation be $ (x-a)^2+y^2=(x+a)^2 $ ?

Comment: it will be a  left handed parabola

Comment: whoops, fixing it right now!

Comment: Argh, I can't delete the answer since it's been accepted. @JieshunWang, for future reference, please wait a couple of hours before accepting to let things like this unfold :)

Comment: I've retracted my downvote as the answer has been fixed.

Answer (score 1):

Given $|z-a|$= $\Re(z)+a$
$$|x+iy-a|=x+a\\|(x-a)+iy|=x+a\\ $$

$$\sqrt{(x-a)^2+y^2}=x+a\\$$

taking square on both side

$$(x-a)^2+y^2=(x+a)^2\\x^2+a^2-2ax+y^2=x^2+a^2+2ax$$

we get $$y^2=4ax$$

This is a right handed parabola with focus
 $(a,0)$

Answer (score 1):

First note that $a$ must be real as it is the difference between a magnitude (real) and the real part of a complex number (also real).

So we can let $z = x+yi$ and proceed as follows:

$\sqrt{(x-a)^2 + y^2}= x+a$

$(x-a)^2 + y^2= (x+a)^2$

Rearrange, use the difference of squares identity,

$2a(2x) = y^2$

$y^2 = 4ax$

which is a parabola that's of the same shape as $y^2 = x$ with some scaling adjustments.

Answer (score 0):

Geometrical $\vert {z-a}\vert$ is distance of Z from point a
And distance of Z from line  .$$ a\bar z + \bar a z + b = 0 $$
Is $$ \vert\frac {a\bar z + \bar a z + b }{2\vert a \vert}\vert$$
In given question Re(z)+a = $ \frac{z}{2}\,+\,\frac{\bar z}{2}+ a $
Which is distance of Z from line.
Hence locus is a parabola.